# Syntax error in arcpy.CreateFishnet_management

Tags: arcpy, vector-grid

I can't seem to find the syntax error in this line. Can anyone else find it?

```
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(Full_Grid, str(NAR_U9.extent.XMin) + " " + str(NAR_U9.extent.YMin), str(NAR_U9.extent.XMin) + " " + str(NAR_U9.extent.YMin + 10), Cell_Size_Width, Cell_Size_Height, "0", "0", , "NO_LABELS", , "POLYLINE")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two optional arguments that you are omitting need an empty quotation `""`.

`arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(Full_Grid, str(NAR_U9.extent.XMin) + " " + str(NAR_U9.extent.YMin), str(NAR_U9.extent.XMin) + " " + str(NAR_U9.extent.YMin + 10), Cell_Size_Width, Cell_Size_Height, "0", "0", "", "NO_LABELS", "", "POLYLINE")`

You are also going to have an error because you are setting the number of rows and number of columns to zero (letting the tool calculate them) without specifying the opposite corner coordinates.